# Where does the charged particle gain energy from when it is placed between two charges $+q$ and $-q$?

Tags: electrostatics, charge, potential-energy

[image]

If a charged particle (Say $+Q$) is placed between two charged   particles of charges $+q$ and $-q$ (are of equal magnitude and those two charges are static),the electric potential in the midpoint is zero as
Net Potential at midpoint=Potential by +q + Potential by -q

```
                     =k(+q)/r +k(-q)/r
                    =0
```

so potential energy at midpoint=Q*0=0J.
But after placing it in the midpoint the charged particle Q will accelerate and gain a velocity as the -ve charge is pulling towards it and +ve is pushing it away from it.
So it gains a kinetic energy as it now has velocity.
But since the electric potential energy is zero,it can't gain energy from there.
SO where does the kinetic energy come from??
plz correct if i have misunderstood as i have been thinking about this for a while

Comment: At the initial position it has no energy, neither potential nor kinetic. But it will move to a position where the potential is negative and the kinetic energy is positive. Those two will cancel out---the total energy is zero, but the kinetic energy is positive because the potential energy can drop below zero. You can also see it as being pushed rightwards and integrated to get the same answer.

Comment: Why don't you calculate the change in potential energy as the particle gains velocity and moves away from the midpoint and see how that compares to the change in kinetic energy.  It's the change that counts.  Remember the zero point of potential energy is arbitrary and is merely a mathematical convenience.